# In Azure DevOps i like to use a remote Azure Repository for my YAML Pipeline, is this possible?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-repos

## Init

I have Organization A with an Azure Repository containing code and YAML pipeline definitions. In Organization B, I would like to use the same code and YAML pipeline definitions for my deployments.
[simple context view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKram.png)

## Question

Is it possible to connect an Azure YAML Pipeline to an Azure Repository hosted within another organization?

I do have this running with BitBucket Cloud Repositry in another instance. But in the case of Azure DevOps from Organisation B to Organisation A i failed to setup. It's hard to find the correct documantion if this is possible and supported scenario or not possible.

## What i have tested so far

I did try to use a generic repository service connection from Azure DevOps in Organisation B to Azure DevOps Organisation A.
[pipeline overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BM4dw.png)

Alternativley i did try a "Azure Repos/Team Foundation Server" service connection. Creating a new pipeline selecting option 1 "Azure Repos Git (YAML)" i can not see the Repository from Organisation A.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not supported to create a YAML pipeline from the repository in another Azure DevOps organization. It is supported from different project only within the same organization.

However, the classic build pipeline can support the repository from another Azure DevOps organization. Maybe, you can consider it.

If your projects really need this feature, I recommend you try to report a feature request on [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/suggest). That will make it more convenient for the product teams to receive and understand your ideas. And your feedback also could be helpful for improving the Azure DevOps products.